# How to setup a Jenkins CI cluster for single/cross platform development?

Tags: jenkins

I have 3 applications that need to be build. One application is Linux-only, one is Windows-only, and one is cross-platform. Currently, I clone the repositories manually on the related build system. I want to automate this process.

The (optimal) solution should be that I have a 2-node-cluster of Jenkins, one Linux node and one Windows node. I setup a build job one one node (no matter which) and define my *build targets* (cross-platform, Linux-only, Windows-only). The job definitions are shared within the Jenkins cluster and do not need to be transferred across the nodes.

How do I setup a 2-node Jenkins "cross-platform" cluster? How to define the *build target* (cross, Linux, Windows) for specific job definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the Windows and Linux executors to Jenkins, be sure to give them appropriate `linux` and `windows` labels.

Then, in your Jenkinsfile, use multiple `agent`s to define several different execution environments.

For instance:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build on Linux') {
            agent { 
                label 'linux'
            }
            steps { 
                sh 'my-build-command'
            }
        }
        stage('Build on Windows') {
            agent {
                label 'windows'
            }
            steps {
                bat 'myBuildCommand' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's an example from the official documentation on how to use `agent` to run different steps on different platforms such as Linux and Windows.](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-multiple-agents)

[Here's the full documentation for the `agent` directive.](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)

This is for declarative pipeline.  If you are using scripted pipelines, use `node()` instead.